# What‘s the meaning of 'activeness' in spark-graphx?

Tags: spark-graphx

The 'activeness' is mentionded in EdgeActiveness.java.

What‘s the meaning of 'activeness' in spark-graphx?

Answer (score 0):

Activeness is exactly as it sounds. It relates to a definition of four states depending on whether the source and destination vertices are *active* or *inactive*. Essentially, graph vertices can choose to deactivate. Consider the example for social networking:

A Facebook user could deactivate their account, but we wouldn't necessarily want to remove them from the user-graph. Their relationships still offer potentially useful information for graph algorithms. Hence, we can simply mark them as inactive, and any user connected to this inactive user would do so via an edge with an `EdgeActiveness` of `Either`, `SrcOnly`, `DstOnly`, or `Neither` depending on the active state of the other user.

The following is mentioned in the publication [From "Think like a Vertex" to "Think like a Graph"](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol7/p193-tian.pdf)

> A vertex carries two states: active and inactive. In the beginning, all vertices are active. A vertex can voluntarily deactivate itself by calling voteToHalt() or be passively activated by some incoming messages from other ver- tices. The overall program terminates if every vertex is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Spark is using Pregel API of GraphX ,Vertex activeness in Pregel is controlled by messages: if a vertex did not 
>   receive a message in the previous iteration, its vertex program will not run 
>   in the current iteration. Also, inactive vertices will not be able to send 
>   messages because by default the sendMsg function will only be run on edges 
>   where at least one of the adjacent vertices received a message.

- http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/graphx-pregel-api-an-example
- https://www.sics.se/~amir/id2221/slides/graph_pregel_graphlab_graphx.pdf